# Trouble with do,while using window.prompt

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a bb game and I have trouble with a do, while loop using a variable that changes using window.prompt. It's supposed that the initial value is null, so the game isn't gonna work till u introduce ur name (min 3 characters).

This is what it's supposed to be:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('lienzo');
canvas.style.backgroundColor = 'lightyellow';

canvas.offsetLeft = 0;
canvas.offsetTop = 0;

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 1;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 1;

const gc = canvas.getContext(
  '2d'
);

const CANVAS_COLOR = 'lightyellow';

const GAP = 10;
const BRICK_ROWS = 3;
const BRICKS_PER_ROW = 8;
const DEBUG = false;

const LEFT_KEY = 37;
const RIGHT_KEY = 39;
const UP_KEY = 38;
const DOWN_KEY = 40;

const play = {

  wall: null,
  ball: null,
  paddle: null,
  player: null,

  gameOver: function() {
    const playerDead = play.player.dead();
    const outOfBricks = play.wall.numAlive();

    return playerDead || outOfBricks === 0;
  },

  buildWall: function() {

    const wall = {
      numBricks: BRICK_ROWS * BRICKS_PER_ROW,
      bricks: [],

      computeBrickSize: function(width, height) {
        const numGaps = BRICKS_PER_ROW - 1;
        const available = (window.innerWidth - (numGaps * GAP));

        return (available / BRICKS_PER_ROW);
      },

      resize: function(width, height) {
        brickWidth = Math.round(play.wall.computeBrickSize());
        brickHeight = Math.round(brickWidth / 5);

        if (DEBUG) console.log(
          `BRICK SIZE => ${brickWidth} ${brickHeight}`
        );

        for (let row = 0; row < BRICK_ROWS; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < BRICKS_PER_ROW; col++) {

            const brick = wall.bricks[
              row * BRICKS_PER_ROW + col
            ];

            brick.width = brickWidth;
            brick.height = brickHeight;
          }
        }
      },

      buildBricks: function() {

        let brickWidth = Math.round(wall.computeBrickSize());
        let brickHeight = Math.round(brickWidth / 5);

        if (DEBUG) console.log(
          `BRICK SIZE => ${brickWidth} ${brickHeight}`
        );

        for (let row = 0; row < BRICK_ROWS; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < BRICKS_PER_ROW; col++) {

            let x = (col * (brickWidth + GAP));
            let y = (row * (brickHeight + GAP));

            const brick = {
              x: x,
              y: y,
              width: brickWidth,
              height: brickHeight,
              color: '#CC0000',
              alive: true,
              paint: function() {
                if (brick.alive) {
                  gc.fillStyle = brick.color;

                  gc.fillRect(
                    brick.x, brick.y,
                    brick.width - 1, brick.height - 1
                  );
                } else {
                  // skip it
                }
              },
            };

            wall.bricks
              .push(
                brick
              );
          }
        }
      },

      detectBallCollision: function(
        ball) {

        let collision = false;

        for (let row = 0; row < BRICK_ROWS && !collision; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < BRICKS_PER_ROW && !collision; col++) {

            const brick = wall.bricks[
              row * BRICKS_PER_ROW + col
            ];

            if (brick.alive) {
              collision = ball.detectBrickCollision(
                brick
              );

              if (collision) {
                brick.alive = false;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },

      paint: function() {

        for (let row = 0; row < BRICK_ROWS; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < BRICKS_PER_ROW; col++) {

            const brick = wall.bricks[
              row * BRICKS_PER_ROW + col
            ];

            brick.paint();
          }
        }
      },

      numAlive: function() {
        let count = 0;

        for (let row = 0; row < BRICK_ROWS; row++) {
          for (let col = 0; col < BRICKS_PER_ROW; col++) {

            const brick = wall.bricks[
              row * BRICKS_PER_ROW + col
            ];

            if (brick.alive) {
              count++;
            }
          }
        }

        return count;
      }
    };

    return wall;
  },

  buildBall: function() {

    const ball = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      r: 16,
      color: '#008800',
      dx: 5,
      dy: 5,
      init: function() {
        ball.x = window.innerWidth / 2,
          ball.y = window.innerHeight / 2
      },
      paint: function() {
        gc.fillStyle = ball.color;

        gc.beginPath();

        gc.arc(
          ball.x, ball.y,
          ball.r,
          0,
          2 * Math.PI
        );

        gc.fill();
        gc.closePath();
      },
      move: function(
        paddle) {

        ball.x += ball.dx;
        ball.y += ball.dy;

        if (ball.y <= 0) {
          ball.dy = -ball.dy;
        }

        const left = paddle.x;
        const right = paddle.x + paddle.w;
        const ballBottom = play.ball.y + play.ball.r;
        const paddleTop = paddle.y;

        const collision = (play.ball.dy > 0) &&
          (ballBottom >= paddleTop) &&
          (left < play.ball.x && play.ball.x < right);

        if (collision) {
          play.ball.dy = -play.ball.dy;
        } else {
          if (ball.y >= canvas.height) {
            play.playerDied();

            if (play.player.dead()) {
              // NOOP
            } else {
              ball.dy = -ball.dy;
            }
          }
        }

        if (ball.x <= 0 || ball.x >= canvas.width) {
          ball.dx = -ball.dx;
        }
      },

      detectBrickCollision: function(
        brick) {

        let collision = false;

        const brickLeft = brick.x;
        const brickRight = brick.x + brick.width;
        const brickTop = brick.y;
        const brickBottom = brick.y + brick.height;

        const ballTop = play.ball.y - play.ball.r;
        const ballBottom = play.ball.y + play.ball.r;
        const ballLeft = play.ball.x - play.ball.r;
        const ballRight = play.ball.x + play.ball.r;

        const ballGoingUp = function(ball) {
          return (ball.dy < 0);
        }

        const ballGoingDown = function(ball) {
          return (ball.dy > 0);
        }

        const ballGoingRight = function(ball) {
          return (ball.dx > 0);
        }

        const ballGoingLeft = function(ball) {
          return (ball.dx < 0);
        }

        const ballInsideBrickDeltaX = function(ball) {
          return (brickLeft < ball.x && ball.x < brickRight);
        }

        const ballInsideBrickDeltaY = function(ball) {
          return (brickTop < ball.y && ball.y < brickBottom);
        }

        // check collision w/bricks's bottom
        collision = ballGoingUp(play.ball) &&
          ballInsideBrickDeltaX(play.ball) &&
          (ballTop <= brickBottom);

        if (collision) {
          play.ball.dy = -play.ball.dy;
        } else {
          // check collision w/bricks's right
          collision = ballGoingLeft(play.ball) &&
            ballInsideBrickDeltaY(play.ball) &&
            (brickLeft < ballLeft && ballLeft <= brickRight);

          if (collision) {
            play.ball.dx = -play.ball.dx;
          } else {
            // check collision w/bricks's left
            collision = ballGoingRight(play.ball) &&
              ballInsideBrickDeltaY(play.ball) &&
              (ballRight >= brickLeft && ballRight < brickRight);

            if (collision) {
              play.ball.dx = -play.ball.dx;
            } else {
              // check collision w/bricks's top
              collision = ballGoingDown(play.ball) &&
                ballInsideBrickDeltaX(play.ball) &&
                (brickBottom < ballBottom && ballBottom <= brickTop);

              if (collision) {
                play.ball.dy = -play.ball.dy;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        return collision;
      }
    };

    return ball;
  },

  buildPaddle: function() {

    const PADDLE_WIDTH = window.innerWidth / 10;
    const PADDLE_HEIGHT = PADDLE_WIDTH / 4;

    const paddle = {
      x: (3 * (window.innerWidth / 4)) - (PADDLE_WIDTH / 2),
      y: window.innerHeight - PADDLE_HEIGHT,
      w: PADDLE_WIDTH,
      h: PADDLE_HEIGHT,
      color: '#0000AA',
      dx: 40,

      init: function() {
        canvas.addEventListener(
          'keydown',
          (event) => {
            console.log(
              event.keyCode
            );

            switch (event.keyCode) {
              case LEFT_KEY:
                play.paddle.x -= play.paddle.dx;

                if (play.paddle.x <= 0) {
                  play.paddle.x = 0;
                }
                break;

              case RIGHT_KEY:
                play.paddle.x += play.paddle.dx;

                const right = play.paddle.x + PADDLE_WIDTH;
                if (right >= canvas.width) {
                  play.paddle.x = canvas.width - PADDLE_WIDTH;
                }
                break;
            }
          }
        );
      },

      paint: function() {
        gc.fillStyle = paddle.color;

        gc.beginPath();

        gc.fillRect(
          paddle.x, paddle.y,
          PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT
        );

        gc.closePath();
      },
      move: function() {
        paddle.x += paddle.dx;

        const right = paddle.x + PADDLE_WIDTH;

        if (paddle.x <= 0 || right >= canvas.width) {
          paddle.dx = -paddle.dx;
        }
      }
    };

    return paddle;
  },

  buildPlayer: function() {
    const player = {
      lives: null,
      decLives: function() {
        player.lives--;
      },
      dead: function() {
        return player.lives === 0;
      },
      name: null,

    }

    return player;
  },

  init: function() {


    canvas.focus();

    window.addEventListener(
      'resize',
      (event) => {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 1;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 1;

        play.wall
          .resize(
            canvas.width,
            canvas.height
          );
      }
    );

    play.wall = play.buildWall();
    play.ball = play.buildBall();
    play.paddle = play.buildPaddle();
    play.player = play.buildPlayer();

    play.wall
      .buildBricks();

    play.paddle
      .init();

    play.ball
      .init();
  },

  clearCanvas: function() {
    gc.clearRect(
      0, 0,
      canvas.width, canvas.height
    );
  },

  paint: function() {
    play.clearCanvas();

    play.wall.paint();
    play.ball.move(
      play.paddle
    );

    play.wall
      .detectBallCollision(
        play.ball
      );

    play.ball.paint();
    play.paddle.paint();
  },

  playerDied: function() {
    play.player
      .decLives();

    if (play.player.dead()) {
      // NOOP
    } else {
      play.ball
        .init();
    }
  },

  render: function() {
    play.paint();

    if (play.gameOver()) {
      play.clearCanvas();

      gc.fillStyle = 'red';
      gc.font = '72px serif';
      gc.fillText(
        'GAME OVER!',
        50,
        100
      );
    } else {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(
        play.render
      );
    }
  },

  run: function() {

    play.init();

    do {
      play.player.name = window.prompt(
        'nombre'
      );
    } while (play.player.name == null && play.player.name.length < 3);

    play.render();
  }
};


play.run();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      border: 0;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="lienzo" tabIndex="0" autofocus></canvas>
  <script src="index-3-1-1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```
const = player{
     name: null,
     lives: null,
}
do{player.name = window.prompt(
   'nombre'
   );}while(player.name = null && player.name.length < 3);
```

It's supposed that `window.prompt` should appear till `player.name` isn't `null` and is longer than 3 however I don't get it.

Comment: `player.name = null` is an **assignment**, not a comparison. You want to check `player.name === null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal viable example would be much shorter. However, your problem is indeed to be found in the one statement you mentioned at the end. Your logic calls for an OR not an AND:

```
while(player.name == null || player.name.length < 3);
```

This way the loop will be run until both conditions are NOT true anymore.

And of course, you need to use the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment `=`.

Comment: `player.name = null` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: Hey, I was still typing ... (my smartphone was playing up in the middle of it) :D